# Override SpringBootJar classes at runtime

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm working with a system where we are creating a SpringBoot micro service.  That micro service will communicate with external systems via a `SystemAdapter` interface. We are creating an API for people to build their own system adapters.  What I'm looking for is a way to startup my micro-service - pass in a jar on the classPath and have it use that implementation of the `SystemAdapater` rather than the default one embedded in the jar.

Is there a straight forward to do this with Gradle and the `bootJar` task of `SpringBoot`.

One approach I tried to take was:

```
bootJar {
    exclude '**/adapters/**'
}

task saJar(type: Jar) {
    from sourceSets.main.output
    include '**/adapters/**'
    baseName 'SA'
}

bootJar.dependsOn(saJar)
```

I tried to write out 2 different Jars but I couldn't get

`java -cp SA.jar -jar microService.jar` to actually work

Thanks for any assistance that can be offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look on spring boot properties launcher, it will allow you to load the external SystemAdapter implementations cleanly.
To enable the PropertiesLauncher:
1. in the main app set the app layout to `ZIP`

> springBoot{
>           mainClass = "..."
>           layout = "ZIP"
>           ... }

2. in the implementation bundle set the layout to `MODULE`

> springBoot{
>           mainClass = "..."
>           layout = "MODULE"
>           ...
>       }

3. Add the following cli arg to point to the folder where external jars are places.

> java -Dloader.path=file:/path/to/SystemAdaptery-implementations-folder
>   -jar main-app.jar

That was for loading the implementations, you can couple it with spring boot ServiceLoader (or simply the jdk service loader) to register the SystemAdaptery implementation instances and manage their invocations.

Comment: So I'm running into: 
> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'layout' for root project

Answer (score 0):

You can have many beans implementing the `SystemAdapter` interface available in the Spring context, you just need to need to make sure they are injected into a `List` field:

```
 List<SystemAdapter> systemAdapters;
```

Then your code just needs to figure out which of these beans should be used.

Comment: Thanks - we are actually doing this but it doesn't address the issue of loading new ones in at run-time and/or overriding existing ones