# Unable to set Layout = ZIP in SpringBoot closure with Gradle

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

This is a follow up on a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58395481/override-springbootjar-classes-at-runtime/58396261#58396261) I've asked.  I'm trying to get a SpringBoot build setup where I can use `propertiesLauncher`.  According to the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-configuration-layouts) I need to us the `ZIP` layout.

So when I add the following block to gradle:

```
springBoot{
    layout='ZIP'
}
```

I get the following error at build time:

> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'layout' for root project 'demo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'demo'.
> Cannot set the value of read-only property 'layout' for root project 'demo' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I'm assuming I'm missing something simple here.  So my questions are as follows:

1) What do I need to do in order for this to compile

2) Am I able to do this w/out using the SpringDependencyManagement plugin as I'm hoping to use Gradle's native BOM support

Thanks,

A sample project is here: https://github.com/jeeftor/spring-boot-layout

And build.gradle looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.9.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.8.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'org.confused'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

springBoot{
    layout='ZIP'
}
```

Comment: Have you resolved it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you write:

```
springBoot{
    layout='ZIP'
}
```

You are giving a closure to the springBoot extension, and anything you write here will either resolve against the extension itself, or to the surrounding scope which is the Gradle Project class in this case.

What happens is that you try to set a variable `layout` that you expect is in the extension, but it isn't. Instead, it just happens that there is a [variable with the same name](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/Project.html#getLayout--) on the Gradle `Project` class. And this variable is read-only, which is why Gradle complains. Of cause, this is not the one you intend to use in the first place.

So now you are probably asking why there isn't there a `layout` variable in the springBoot extension as is says in the documentation. And the answer to that is that you are looking at the documentation for Spring Boot 1.4, whereas you are using Spring Boot 2.1. If you head over to the [documentation for the version you are using](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.x/reference/html/index.html), you will see that there are no longer a layout property. Instead, if you like to create a zip distribution of your application, you can use the `application` plugin. But that is not going to make it use the PropertiesLauncher.

The Gradle plugin does not have any documentation of how to use the PropertiesLauncher, but if you use the executable jar format (you can also use an executable war), it looks like this:

```
bootJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher'
    }
}
```

You can then load extra jars with `java -Dloader.path=path/to/extra/jars -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, an environment variable or one of the other methods as specified in the documentation. Note that you can't use the `bootRun` task without additional tweaks, as it doesn't use PropertiesLauncher.

You also asked about using the native BOM support in Gradle. You can remove the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin, and instead use a platform dependency like this:

```
dependencies {
    implementation platform(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-dependencies', version: '2.1.9.RELEASE')
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work with spring boot 2.0 but thats ok :)