# PropertiesLauncher command line arguments not working with Spring Boot executable Jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, executable-jar

So I have basic multi-module Spring Boot project. The goal, that I had was to build executable jar and pass additional properties with the help of `-Dloader.path=...`.

For some reason (if I understand purpose of this argument) `loader.path` is being ignored completely.

My project structure is following:

```
\-
|--conf
|---default
|--pets-api
|--pets-app (this module contains the Main-Class)
|--pets-domain
|--pets-infrastructure
```

Since no custom `active profile` is being passed it uses "default". Jar contains `application-default.propeties` file, that has single configuration `server.servlet.context-path=/v1`.

`/conf/default` location has 2 properties files:

- `application.properties`
- `random.properties` - this is bind to `@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "...")` inside application

When I run it normally everything is fine `java -jar pets-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`. It just uses `application-default.properties` file and that is it.

Now when I am trying to utilize `-Dloader.path` argument as in `java -Dloader.path=PATH/TO/conf/default -jar pets-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` it starts application same as before, as if I am not adding 2 more file to classpath.

What is used:

- Java 17
- Spring Boot 2.6.12
- Gradle

Did anyone come across this as well? Any suggestion on how to resolve it?

PS. If there is need to see the code, I can upload it to GitHub.

Comment: Check if this helps in anyway: https://www.behindjava.com/java-spring-classpath/

Comment: @pringi I am sorry, I forgot to mention, that I use Gradle and secondly as far as I remember `layout: ZIP` is not supported in new version of Spring Boot. As it is mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/58418478/318306

Comment: @pringi I take it back. Option 2 worked as far as I can tell. Need to test it more, but so far best result.